# returning in a method with a try/catch block

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, return, try-catch

Hello I am having trouble with the logic of returning my linkedList in a try/catch block. I currently have:

```
public static LinkedList<String> makeList(String textName) {

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(textName), "UTF8"));

        LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();
        String line;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            ll.add(line);
        }
        return ll;
        in.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Obviously something is wrong with the return statement only being in the try block but when I also have "return null;" outside of the try and catch I still get an error. The help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly did you try? What does the error say?

Comment: I actually just figured it out right after I posted. I moved my return under my in.close(); and added a return null; inbetween the last two braces. It originally wouldn't run because it suggested that I change my method to void which isn't what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

Your `in.close();` can not be reached as you're returning right before it. And yes, you should also add a return after the try catch block

Answer (score 0):

Move your in.close() to a finally block.